# Text makes image to go down, thus messing up UI

Tags: html, css

I wrote an UI like this:
[image: img]
Here is the code:
**`HTMLcode:`**

```
<div class = "category2 ctg">
    <span class = "ctgryName2">Junos OS Fundamentals</span>
    <span class = "ctgryIcon2 pull-right"></span>
    <span class = "Icon2 pull-right"></span>
</div>
```

**`CSS code:`**

```
.category2{
        width: 49%;
        line-height : 35px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;  
    }
.ctg{
        float: left;
    }
.ctgryName2{
        color: grey;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-family: "robotRegular";
        overflow: auto;
    }
.ctgryIcon2{
        background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/challenger-inactive_icon.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: block;           
        height: 28px;
        margin-top: 0.7%;
        width: 30px;
    }
    .Icon2{
        background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/practice-inactive_icon.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        display: block;           
        height: 28px;
        margin-top: 0.7%;
        width: 30px;
    }
```

If I add extra text like this:

```
<div class = "category2 ctg">
    <span class = "ctgryName2">Junos OS Fundamentals abracardabra blah blah lorem lpsum</span>
    <span class = "ctgryIcon2 pull-right"></span>
    <span class = "Icon2 pull-right"></span>
</div>
```

then UI becomes like this:
[image: img1]
I want the text to be adjusted in a way that whole text and image will be in same line. How can I do it?

Comment: Put both of the divs in a new div with horizontal alignment

Comment: It isn't working....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taq9vebt/

Comment: I checked that jsfiddle. The images aren't in div, they are in same div, but in different spans. So can I apply horizontal aligning?

Comment: Why not put them in another div? http://jsfiddle.net/taq9vebt/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
<span class = "ctgryName2" style="white-space:nowrap;">Junos OS Fundamentals abracardabra blah blah lorem lpsum</span>
```

For more info on `white-space`, check this [link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space) out.

Comment: After using `style="white-space:nowrap;"`, text will be in same line,but images won't be in same line.They move down. I want both images and text to be on the same line even though long text is added.